# How to work with mocks when the function uses lambda arguments

Tags: python, mocking

I'm testing some code that uses `pysqld` library from Amazon. One of the functions is `execute_lambda`, which accepts a lambda as param (it's a transaction that you can pass some functions to be executed).

I'm trying to mock this calls, but I can't make sure of the params. Lets see an example:

```
with session() as s:

    s.execute_lamda(lambda x: function(param1, param2))
```

When I go to the test, and check the mock calls:

```
(Pdb) self.mocks["pyqldb"]["mock"]().get_session().__enter__().execute_lambda.mock_calls
[call(<function init_schema.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fd80c97a4d0>, <function init_schema.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fd80c97a200>),
 call(<function init_schema.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fd80c97a5f0>, <function init_schema.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fd80c97a680>),
 call(<function init_schema.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fd80c97a7a0>, <function init_schema.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fd80c97a710>),
 call(<function init_schema.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fd80c97a8c0>, <function init_schema.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fd80c97a830>),
 call(<function init_schema.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fd80c97a9e0>, <function init_schema.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fd80c97a950>),
 call(<function init_schema.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fd80c97ab00>, <function init_schema.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fd80c97aa70>),
 call().__next__(),
 call().__next__().__str__()]
```

How can I go to each call and check the params for lambda?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [call_args_list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args_list) to get all the calls with args.

```
....execute_lambda.call_args_list
```

example

```
>>> mock = Mock(return_value=None)
>>> mock()
>>> mock(3, 4)
>>> mock(key='fish', next='w00t!')
>>> mock.call_args_list
[call(), call(3, 4), call(key='fish', next='w00t!')]
>>> expected = [(), ((3, 4),), ({'key': 'fish', 'next': 'w00t!'},)]
>>> mock.call_args_list == expected
```

True
ref - https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args_list

Comment: Maybe I wasnt clear in my question, it´s easy to get execute_lambda args. The problem is: after get the args from the function, how I can get the args of the lambda expressions?